# Rider 2019.3.4 запуск UnitTest через xUnit в Debug приводит к ошибке запуска тестов

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rider, xunit

перестали работать тесты (xUnit) на проектах под IDE Rider.
Для чистоты эксперимента создал новый Solution с 1 проектом xUnit.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Тестовый класс

```
public class UnitTest1
 {
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
    }
 }
```

в DEBUG этот тест не запускается. В RUN все отрабатывает.
статус ошибки `Inonclusive: Test not run`

[image: ошибка тестов в rider]

ПОЛНЫЙ ЛОГ:

```
00:31:47.641 |T| Launch: 70673488-fb9e-407a-87d1-27bd865d85b7 >> RiderDebugHostController.AfterLaunchStarted
00:31:47.642 |T| Launch: 70673488-fb9e-407a-87d1-27bd865d85b7 << RiderDebugHostController.AfterLaunchStarted
00:31:47.642 |I| BuildStage started
00:31:47.642 |I| Build policy: Automatic
00:31:48.594 |I| 0 projects built
00:31:48.595 |I| BuildStage completed
00:31:48.595 |I| RefreshProjectPropertiesStage started
00:31:48.595 |I| RefreshProjectPropertiesStage completed
00:31:48.595 |I| DiscoveryStage started
00:31:48.595 |I| Test exploration required for 0 projects
00:31:48.595 |I| DiscoveryStage completed
00:31:48.595 |I| BuildPipelineStage started
00:31:48.595 |I| BuildPipelineStage completed
00:31:48.595 |I| ApplyRulesStage started
00:31:48.595 |V| Running elements from criterion: {TestAncestorCriterion: xUnit::EFBCAFD7-ACA0-4256-AADD-DD8AD8938570::.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1::Tests.RepositoryTest.OperatorRepositoryTest.Can_Add_New_Operator_Test}
00:31:48.595 |I| Got 1 elements (1 explicit) to run
00:31:48.595 |V| Marking 1 elements as Pending
00:31:48.595 |V| Marking elements as Pending completed
00:31:48.595 |V| Distributing 1 elements into runs
00:31:48.597 |V| Distributing elements completed
00:31:48.597 |I| Created 1 unit-test runs
00:31:48.597 |I| ApplyRulesStage completed
00:31:48.597 |I| RunTestsStage started
00:31:48.598 |I| Running up to 1 unit-test runs in parallel
00:31:48.598 |I| Run: 08cc6320-e48c-4f6d-8006-3eabdf419b5c - Starting
00:31:48.598 |V|     Provider: xUnit.net
    Target Framework: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1
    Strategy: XunitDotNetVsTestRunStrategy
    Runtime Enviroment: DotNetCoreRuntimeEnvironment
  Project: Tests
  TargetFrameworkId: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1
  TargetPlatform: X64
00:31:48.598 |T| Run: 08cc6320-e48c-4f6d-8006-3eabdf419b5c >> RiderDebugHostController.PrepareForRun
00:31:48.598 |T| Run: 08cc6320-e48c-4f6d-8006-3eabdf419b5c << RiderDebugHostController.PrepareForRun
00:31:48.598 |T| Register handler for message type 'TestSession.Message', protocol version '1'
00:31:48.598 |T| Register handler for message type 'ProtocolVersion', protocol version '<unset>'
00:31:48.598 |T| Register handler for message type 'TestSession.Connected', protocol version '<unset>'
00:31:48.598 |T| Register handler for message type 'TestExecution.CustomTestHostLaunch', protocol version '1'
00:31:48.598 |T| Register handler for message type 'TestExecution.Completed', protocol version '1'
00:31:48.598 |T| Register handler for message type 'TestExecution.StatsChange', protocol version '1'
00:31:48.602 |I| [ProcessStartInfoPatchResult]
  Original request: DotNetCoreRequest
  Success: True
  ErrorMessage: <Empty>
  Original StartInfo: FileName = 'vstest', Arguments = '/port:51533  ', WorkDir = 'D:\C#\DDD\TacticalDdd\Tests'
  Patched  StartInfo: FileName = 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe', Arguments = '"vstest" /port:51533  ', WorkDir = 'D:\C#\DDD\TacticalDdd\Tests'

00:31:48.602 |I| Starting process: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe "vstest" /port:51533  
00:31:48.614 |I| Started process with pid 22220
00:31:48.893 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Connected'
00:31:48.893 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Connected'
00:31:48.897 |T| Processing message 'ProtocolVersion'
00:31:48.897 |T| Processed message 'ProtocolVersion'
00:31:48.897 |I| Using test adapter: D:\C#\DDD\TacticalDdd\Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll
00:31:48.900 |T| RunSettings: 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetPlatform>X64</TargetPlatform>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
00:31:49.229 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:49.229 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:49.229 |I| [xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.3+1b45f5407b (64-bit .NET Core 3.1.7)
00:31:49.575 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:49.575 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:49.575 |I| [xUnit.net 00:00:00.35]   Starting:    Tests
00:31:51.115 |T| Processing message 'TestExecution.StatsChange'
00:31:51.115 |T| Processed message 'TestExecution.StatsChange'
00:31:51.115 |W| Transition declined: Transition from state <v1.HostBinding> on event <remote::1.TestExecution.StatsChange>.
00:31:51.161 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.161 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.161 |I| [xUnit.net 00:00:01.93]     Tests.RepositoryTest.OperatorRepositoryTest.Can_Add_New_Operator_Test [FAIL]
00:31:51.162 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |I| [xUnit.net 00:00:01.93]       CSharpFunctionalExtensions.ResultFailureException`1[[ApplicationCore.Domain.DomainModel.Errors.ErrorAll, ApplicationCore.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] : You attempted to access the Value property for a failed result. A failed result has no Value.
00:31:51.162 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |I| [xUnit.net 00:00:01.93]       Stack Trace:
00:31:51.162 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |I| [xUnit.net 00:00:01.93]            at CSharpFunctionalExtensions.Result`2.get_Value()
00:31:51.162 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |I| [xUnit.net 00:00:01.93]         D:\C#\DDD\TacticalDdd\Tests\RepositoryTest\OperatorRepositoryTest.cs(34,0): at Tests.RepositoryTest.OperatorRepositoryTest.Can_Add_New_Operator_Test()
00:31:51.162 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.162 |I| [xUnit.net 00:00:01.93]         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
00:31:51.170 |T| Processing message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.170 |T| Processed message 'TestSession.Message'
00:31:51.170 |I| [xUnit.net 00:00:01.94]   Finished:    Tests
00:31:51.220 |T| Processing message 'TestExecution.StatsChange'
00:31:51.222 |T| Processed message 'TestExecution.StatsChange'
00:31:51.222 |W| Transition declined: Transition from state <v1.HostBinding> on event <remote::1.TestExecution.StatsChange>.
00:31:51.223 |T| Processing message 'TestExecution.Completed'
00:31:51.223 |T| Processed message 'TestExecution.Completed'
00:31:51.237 |I| Process C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe:22220 has exited with code (1)
00:31:51.237 |I| Output stream: Џа®Ја ¬¬  Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool ўҐабЁЁя16.7.0
(б) Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв (Microsoft Corporation). ‚бҐ Їа ў  § йЁйҐ­л.



00:31:51.237 |T| Run: 08cc6320-e48c-4f6d-8006-3eabdf419b5c >> RiderDebugHostController.CleanupAfterRun
00:31:51.237 |T| Run: 08cc6320-e48c-4f6d-8006-3eabdf419b5c << RiderDebugHostController.CleanupAfterRun
00:31:51.238 |I| Run: 08cc6320-e48c-4f6d-8006-3eabdf419b5c - Finished
00:31:51.238 |I| RunTestsStage completed
00:31:51.238 |W| C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe:22220 exited with exit code (1)
Output stream: Џа®Ја ¬¬  Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool ўҐабЁЁя16.7.0
(б) Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв (Microsoft Corporation). ‚бҐ Їа ў  § йЁйҐ­л.



00:31:51.238 |I| FinishLaunchStage started
00:31:51.238 |I| Finishing launch
00:31:51.238 |W| Element Tests.RepositoryTest.OperatorRepositoryTest.Can_Add_New_Operator_Test was left pending after its run completion.
00:31:51.238 |I| Launch is finished
00:31:51.238 |I| FinishLaunchStage completed
00:31:51.238 |T| Launch: 70673488-fb9e-407a-87d1-27bd865d85b7 >> RiderDebugHostController.BeforeLaunchFinished
00:31:51.238 |T| Launch: 70673488-fb9e-407a-87d1-27bd865d85b7 << RiderDebugHostController.BeforeLaunchFinished
```

Если выделить Warning ошибки:

```
 10:11:23.761 |W| Transition declined: Transition from state <v1.HostBinding> on event <remote::1.TestExecution.StatsChange>.
 10:11:23.787 |W| Element xUnittest.UnitTest1.Test1 was left pending after its run completion.
```

Проекты с другими тест адаптерами (`Nunit и MSTest`) также не работают в `DEBUG`

Кроме этого `VS2019(16.7.1) + Resharper` также не запускает `xUnit` через Resharper, с такими же ошибками.
ХОТЯ `MSTest из VS2019` запускается нормально в `DEBUG`.

ошибка из `VS2019`

```
  WARN Transition declined: Transition from state <v1.HostBinding> on event <remote::1.TestExecution.StatsChange>.
  WARN Element Shared.Test.BorderSubStringTest.Set_DelimiterSign_None_Include_Both_Border_Test was left pending after its run completion.
```

Что-то повлияло и на Resharper в VS2019 и на Rider.

похоже ошибка при вызове dotnet.exe:19460

```
00:26:46.101 |W| C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe:19460 exited with exit code (1)
Output stream: Џа®Ја ¬¬  Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool ўҐабЁЁя16.7.0
(б) Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв (Microsoft Corporation). ‚бҐ Їа ў  § йЁйҐ­л.
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже поможет только обновление Rider и Resharper до версии 2020.2

https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009300279-Unable-to-debug-xunit-tests